# JQuery alternative to .die().live() in ajaxed content?

Tags: jquery, ajax, bind, live, die

I have a form that's ajaxed in, and within that form it generates new inputs, and these new inputs have events attached to them by the `.live()` within the initial ajaxed form.

So, the problem I'm having happens when I close this ajaxed form and then open it again without refreshing: I have 2 live events bound to each individual element that should only have 1 live event.

The way I see getting around this is preceding each `.live()` with a `.die()` to clear out all previously attached `live()` ?

I am wondering if there is a cleaner, or more appropriate way of handling this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're aware how `.live()` works, right?  You call it *once*, and the event handler attaches to the document and handles the event for all elements that match that selector, *even if they're added in the future*.  You don't call `.live()` each time you add elements; if you're using it correctly, you only have to call `.die()` if you want to stop handling that particular event altogether, or want to change/replace the handler.

Short version: The cleaner, more appropriate alternative is to quit calling `.live()` when you don't need to.

Comment: I don't think you quite understand, the way I have this form setup, is that it's loading the script every time it's loaded, that's just how the mvc I'm working with is setup. So - everytime the form is loaded the script loads in - close the form, reopen and the script reloads again.

Comment: So, live is being called each time as a click event won't suffice, since the live event is being attached to newly created elements after the initial form load within the form.

Comment: Then you have the form set up wrong.  `.live()` should be called *once*.  If you want to attach an event every time the form loads, then use regular events and attach at the right time.  Unless you're talking about some weird scenario...in which case you're gonna need to provide code, cause chances are you're doing something you shouldn't be.

Comment: @BraydonBatungbacal `live` is event delegation to `document`... there is absolutely no need to use `live` from that script. Either use event delegation to the closest mutual parent every time the script loads or attach `live` from an initial script that runs only once. Either way, please learn how `live` works and what it does :'(

Comment: just to further add some confusion to the mix: `live` is now deprecated and you should use `on` (as per http://api.jquery.com/live/)